# Calculating the color distance between 2 Images in R

Tags: r, image, colors, comparison, distance

I am trying to measure the color distance between 2 images. Using the guidelines mentioned on https://www.compuphase.com/cmetric.htm I would like to give different weight-ages to R,G and B components.

The equation for calculating the distances is sqrt((((512+rMean)*r*r)/256) + 4*g*g + (((767-rMean)*b*b)/256)). More clearly represented in the image link below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF47T.jpg

How do I calculate the average values of R,G and B for an image? Is it the right approach ?

Comment: Your real question seems to be "how to calculate the average value of R,G,B" of an image. But this is a question for you. It depends on what do you want to achieve. A gray image and a image with 3 bands (red, green, blue) will have the same average. It is what do you want?  Also colour difference: you got some formulas, but it really depends on what do you want. Differences are not really comparable (also after the correction in the first links).

Comment: I guess you are right. My problem is calculating average values of R, G and B. What I want to achieve is to compare the color difference between images of different apparels. Packages like 'colordistance' are not giving a very convincing outcome.

Comment: Colour difference is a difficult topic. The most current model can calculate precisely only differences of similar colours. For the other cases, distances can not be comparable. So "not convincing outcome" is a yet unsolved problem. This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference will give you much more models and history (compared of your first link).